# Extracting bulding heights from height map into attribute table

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, features

In QGIS, I have a layer with polygon outlines of buildings and a height map over the area, I would like to extract the height of the buildings from the map and insert it into the attribute of the appropriate polygons, so I  can extrude them into that height. The heights are not in the attribute table already.

I have tried using the "Sample Raster Values" plugin, but it crashes immediately and I have been unable to find other solutions.

Comment: Have you tried `add raster values to features`?

Answer (score 1):

The Zonal Statistics plugin (Processing) did the job. I first took the height of the surface scan and, then applied the plugin again to the tempary layer created and then apple the plugin to the tarrain scan. Then I subtracted the values to get the height above ground.